# Operation could destabilize the runtime. MVC App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting an Operation could destabilize the runtime error message on a testing machine but doesn't happen locally or on a production server. The Error I am getting is unspecific and gives me no clues. I have searched the web looking for a solution with out any success for this specific case. Any Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The project is a simple MVC 4 application with all dll's deployed to the bin folder.

```
Operation could destabilize the runtime.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +17
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +1177
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +305
```

Comment: It would help immensely if you provided a concise code example that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is there is not specific line of code or url route that causes this.. happens on any page/url load. That's why it is so puzzling and hard to solve

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. But only on the servers of our customer. 
On our own webserver (which has the same software components) it works like
a charm.

Very frustrating problem, because there seems no solution for it.